# elementary OS hangs at boot at 'Restoring resolver state…'

Tags: release-freya, boot

I'm running elementary Freya 64 bit and using the Nvidia binary driver v340.76.

Yesterday some upgrades were installed, including apparently the kernel version `3.16.0-46-generic`.

Today I rebooted the system and it hanged on `Restoring resolver state…`. The only way I could get it to boot was to select the previous kernel (`3.16.0-45-generic`) from the advanced options.

I've tried the answer given [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/478205/55128), basically adding `acpi=force` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` :

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi=force”
sudo update-grub
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Enter username and password
- run

  ```
  sudo apt-get -f install`
  sudo reboot
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to uninstall the new (broken) kernel

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.16.0-46-generic
```

Reboot